# Android: Most easy and robust way to handle network operations

Tags: android, android-asynctask, network-programming

Mostly we handle network things in AsyncTask(doInBackground method). I have googled many times to find the most easy and robust way to handle network things. I have also searched here to find the appropriate answer. But still I didn't.

Maximum developers(including me) like to handle this with AsyncTask. But I don't think this is the perfect way. I have faced many problems(like slow process, ANR(Application Not Responding) for this.

So I am excepting the best answer, which will help me and many developers to handle network things in a best way.

Comment: Agreed. I've tweaked AsyncTask to make it less Activity-lifecycle-dependent in my apps but I'm not really satisfied by the solution. A Service looks like the right way to do things but again, it also has its downsides. 
Like you, i'd like to see a foolproof method that works in all cases and which design looks good.

Comment: You could use this, they recommended at the last Google I/O, Volley library: [link](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)